# Passing array of objects into AWS Amplify GraphQL API mutation

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify's GraphQL API on my React Native app. I have an array of objects in my app like so:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
   {
       id: someid,
       thing: thing,
       otherThing: otherThing
   },
   {
       id: someid,
       thing: thing,
       otherThing: otherThing
   }
]);
```

What would this need to look like in my `schema.graphql`? I currently have this defined like so:

```
type someThing @model {
  UserID: String!
  thingName: String
  thingID: String! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["UserID"])
  data: [AWSJSON]
}
```

I'm currently getting this error in my app after calling `createSomeThing` mutation where I pass `data: data` as an input:

`Variable 'data' has an invalid value. Unable to parse {id=8f3aa794-1881-4eaa-ba4e-0ac979b5b0a6, thing=pasta, otherThing=one} as valid JSON.`

What's the issue here? Did I define this incorrectly in the `schema.graphql`? Or do I need to transform the data before passing into my mutation?

Comment: Check the `data` submitted if it is a valid JSON.

Comment: I actually had to pass the array of objects in as a string

Answer (score 0):

Solved by passing in data as a string, simply `JSON.Stringify(data)`